# How to replace â€? generated from right double quote in a String?

Tags: java, string

I have `“excused”` in a text file. I used java's `BufferReader.readLine()` to read it into a String s, s became `â€œexcusedâ€?`.

I used `s = s.replace("â€œ","&ldquo");` and it did the replacement.

However `s = s.replace("â€?","&rdquo");` did not make the replacement.

I tested the following lines in my main method:

```
String t = "â€? test";
System.out.println(t);
t = t. replace("â€?","&rdquo");
System.out.println(t);
```

which did turn t into `&rdquo test`, why did `replace()` not work for the string read in from the text file? Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that you are reading the file using incorrect encoding. It looks like the file is encoded using UTF-8, but you are reading it using system default encoding which is cp1252 on your system. The `"“"` character in UTF-8 is encoded as three bytes: `E2` `80` `9C` which correspond to `"â€œ"` in [cp1252](http://www.cp1252.com/). Try to specify encoding explicitly:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
               new FileReader(myFile), "UTF-8"));
```

Or better in Java-7 (UTF-8 encoding is used automatically by `Files.newBufferedReader`):

```
BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(myFileName));
```

As for why replacement does not work. The UTF-8 for `"”"` is `E2` `80` `9D`, but `9D` is not a question mark, it's just an illegal character in cp1252 (it simply absent in the [table](http://www.cp1252.com/)), so when you read, it's replaced with special unicode code point `\uFFFD` which denotes illegal character. But even though it's displayed as question mark, it's another character. And you are replacing the question mark, not for illegal character, thus it does not replaced.